# Trying to insert and update in two seperate tables from a single controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am facing an issue where I am trying to insert a record in one table and simultaneously update in another table. I am using Laravel 7 and my code is below

```
public function addSingle(Request $request)
  {
    $industries_id = $request->industry_id;
    $application_no = $request->application_no;
    $consent_for = $request->consent_for;
    $application_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->application_date));
    $consentData = Consent::firstOrCreate([
      'application_no' => $application_no,
      'applied_on' => $application_date,
      'consent_for' => $consent_for,
    ]);
    if($consentData->save()) {
      $getIndustryColor = Industry::where('industry_id', $industries_id)->get();
      dd($getIndustryColor);
      $response_array['message'] = 'Consent Added Successfully';
    }
      echo json_encode($response_array);
  }
```

Now the problem is ***$consentData*** is getting saved as desired but after that when I am trying to get the data in the ***if condition*** from **Industry** table I get nothing back. Even the ***dd*** is not showing up. Basically I want to update the **Industry** table in the **if block** which is not working; so I tried to check if I am getting any value if I query the Industry table. But it also shows no output.

Can anyone please point me where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: I think in  `Consent::firstOrCreate` you are not adding `'industry_id' => $industries_id `

Comment: No. the entry in Consent table is okay. and the query is saving the data. But the problem lies in the if condition where its not able to get any data.

Comment: got it, you are using different models, I would try to echo something before `$getIndustryColor = Industry::where` to see if I entered in `if($consentData->save())`, the second thing I would try to give static value `where('industry_id', 1` ` to see if I even get a result from model

Comment: Yes they are different models. Can't I use that. becoz I have defined on the top of the page. ?

Comment: Try to get the last inserted record id and check it in if condition `$consentData->id`.

Comment: You can definitely use them... I want to see if you save method works, and code entered in if statement,  try to replace `if($consentData->save())` with `if($consentData)`

Comment: why are you calling `save` ... `firstOrCreate` either returns an existing record or gives you a newly created record .... where is this "update" you are talking about in the title of this question?

Comment: @lagbox: Yes I have removed the save method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function addSingle(Request $request)
  {
    $industries_id = $request->industry_id;
    $application_no = $request->application_no;
    $consent_for = $request->consent_for;
    $application_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->application_date));
    $consentData = Consent::firstOrCreate([
      'application_no' => $application_no,
      'applied_on' => $application_date,
      'consent_for' => $consent_for,
    ]);

    $consentData->save();

    if(!is_null($consentData) && $consentData) {
      $getIndustryColor = Industry::where('industry_id', $industries_id)->get();
      dd($getIndustryColor);
      $response_array['message'] = 'Consent Added Successfully';
    }
      echo json_encode($response_array);
  }
```

Comment: `$consentData` can't be `null` if you can call `save` on it, so that check doesn't mean anything ... and objects are always true, so the `if` statement is basically `if (true)` so its not needed

Answer (score 0):

this line `$getIndustryColor = Industry::where('industry_id', $industries_id)->get();`

first check that your field's name in db is indeed 'industry_id'

second do you expect a collection of Industry elements or just one? If last - try change your query to

```
$getIndustryColor = Industry::where('industry_id', $industries_id)->first();
```

Comment: I want only one industry details basically a single column only. The 'industry_id' column name is correct also. but inside the if loop it doesnot show me anything. even a static echo also